# Meteor MUP deployment failed

Tags: meteor, deployment, mup

Meteor version 2.1.
MUP version 1.5.9.

While deploying my Meteor App, deployment fails and reverts to the previous version.

Message I get is:

`Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.`

I get no other messages, have no clue what is happening or why.

Comment: I suspect that your app was deployed but never reached a state of running where it was considered "alive" by mup, could that be? Does your app do anything heavy on start?

Comment: @ChristianFritz Not really, nothing on the server side that is heavy. This only started recently, didn't do any big changes on the backend.